# ASP.NET HttpResponse Cookies null check

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse, httpcookie

I have a null check in code that is checking to see whether a cookie exists in the response object already:

```
         if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["CookieName"] != null)
        {
            sessionCookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["CookieName"];
            cookieValue = sessionCookie.Value;
        }
```

When I check through the debugger the key doesn't exist before the check, but it does exists after the check. Thus the return value from the cookie is null. Does checking for a cookies existence automatically create the cookie?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This happens because HttpContext.Current is associated with the thread that the request is currently executing on. On a different thread, the framework has no way to know which request you want to use.

There are ways to fix this-- for example .NET's BackgroundWorker can propagate context to another thread. The Asynchronous Pages support in ASP.NET will also propagate context correctly.

So you have two options: either rewrite all your async code to use context-passing async mechanisms like BackgroundWorker or Async Pages, or change your code to check for HttpContext.Current==null before trying to access any properties of HttpContext.Current

Comment: Makes sense, I think I'll need to check on the null value then.

Comment: sounds good.. let us know how it turns out for you.. gald I could lend you a helping hand...

Comment: I would also make sure that where you are expecting to see / assign the cookie ["CookieName"] for example that you try to assign it .. sort of like if you were to assign a Session["MySession"] = some variable.. does this make sense...?

Comment: No idea why this is the accepted answer. It seems to have very little to do with the question. The answer is yes, calling Response.Cookies["CookieName"] in any manner actually creates the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **yes**, calling `Response.Cookies["CookieName"]` in any manner actually creates the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

That case, when the first answer contains a nonsense not related to the question.

Every time when you do the check:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["CookieName"] != null)
```

this line of code not only checks, whether a cookie exists, but also **creates** a new empty cookie. Even `Get` method creates<sup>[[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezy11xy2(v=vs.85).aspx#Anchor_1)]</sup> the new cookie implicitly.

You can use the code like this:

```
Cookie existing_cookie = null;
foreach (Cookie c in HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies)
{
    if ("CookieName" == c.Name)
    {
        existing_cookie = c;
        break;
    }
}
if (null != existing_cookie)
{
    // exists
}
```

Or use `LINQ` methods to do almost the same.